# Prestashop add a counter and use while in smarty file as the reference how?

Tags: php, jquery, smarty, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I have my code in php for some other project is like this

```
<div class="post-wrap">
  $i = 0;
  while ( have_posts() )
  $i++;
  if($i==1) {
    $class= 'active';
  }
  else {
    $class= '';
  }

 <div class="box '.$class.'"></div>
 endwhile;
 </div>
```

Now this gives the output like

```
<div class="box active"></div>
 <div class="box"></div>
 <div class="box"></div>
```

In this way I have made all the posts fadein and fadeout by jQuery.

with the same reference I want to make fadein and fadeout some texts. For that I have developed module. In that I am getting all the values from database. So my code for module like this

```
public function hookfooter($params) {
  $popup_styles = "SELECT * FROM "._DB_PREFIX_."database ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 1";
  $popup_styles_settings = Db::getInstance()->ExecuteS($popup_styles);
  $this->context->smarty->assign('PopupStyles',$popup_styles_settings);
  return $this->display(__FILE__, 'views/templates/front/footer-display.tpl');
 }
```

Here I have fetched the data and I have assigned the values to smarty.

Inside smarty my code is like this

```
 {foreach from=$sliderValues item=row}
  <div class="box">name</div>
  <div class="box">name2</div>
  <div class="box">name3</div>
 {/foreach}
```

but here I don't know how to use while and make loop counter so that I can add class active for jquery.
So can somone kindly tell me how to make this work? Any help and suggestions will be really appreciable. Thanks

Comment: What is the content of `$sliderValues`?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is quite confusing, but I suppose you just need to use the [@iteration property](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.foreach.tpl#foreach.property.iteration):

```
{foreach $sliderValues as $row}
{if $row@iteration == 1}
... do something ...
{/if}
```